# ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity.Несовпадение хэш-кодов объектов

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

Для работы с `Identity` в проекте существуют: контроллер(`AccountController`) и сервис (`IdentityService`).
Оба класса имеют поля:
 
`UserManager (Type: UserManager<AuthUser>)` и 
`AuthenticationManager(Type: IAuthenticationManager)`.
Инициализируются они объектом 
`HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<AuthUserManager>()` и 
`HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication` соответствено.
В сервис передается экземпляр типа `IOwinContext`, с помощью которого поля так же инициализируются.
В контроллере определен метод возвращающий хэш-коды этих объектов. Хэш-коды объектов `UserManager` совпадают, однако хэш-коды объектов 
`AuthenticationManager` отличаются. Почему так?